# Sharing Facebook Access Tokens Across Apps

Tags: oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I want to provide a service using the facebook api to third parties.  Is it possible for us to share access tokens?  If the third party gives my service a user's access token, can I access that users data even if my app_id & secret do not match the app that requested it?

Should I have the users go through a separate oauth flow on my site even if they have already completed it for the other third party?

Thanks.

-ken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding:

> Is it possible for us to share access tokens?

and,

> can I access that users data even if my app_id & secret do not match the app that requested it?

The answer is `No`. From the specs [OAuth2 section 10.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-25#section-10.3):

> > Access token credentials (as well as any confidential access token attributes) MUST be kept confidential in transit and storage, and only shared among the authorization server, the resource servers the access token is valid for, and the client to whom the access token is issued.

---

> Should I have the users go through a separate oauth flow on my site even if they have already completed it for the other third party?

The answer is `Yes`. If you're using facebook as authorization server, and you restart the oauth flow again, your user will only need to approve your other app (third party).

Comment: What if you have an app and a website which work together (let's say Twitter and the Twitter app). If Twitter wanted to use OAuth2 for authentication with a third party (Google for example) would you have to authenticate both the app and the website separately? Seems very clumsy and a bad experience for the user.

Comment: I would interpret the quote from the specs as "yes, it's possible", but "no, you must not do it", because it would violate security.  If it wasn't possible to share tokens, you wouldn't need to keep them secure.

Answer (score 10):

Even that user access token is issued only for one app it can be easily used from any other application.

Example:

1. Get access token for "Graph API Explorer" application here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me and make a request - you will see your data.
2. Copy access token and open other machine|browser and go to https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=[access_token] - you still able to retrieve information about your Facebook user!

Here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/ it mentioned that

> Our Data Policies explicitly prohibit any sharing of an Access Token for your app with any other app. However, we do allow developers to share Tokens between a native implementation and a server implementation of the same App (ie. using the same App ID) as long as the transfer takes place using HTTPS.

Comment: That excerpt from the FB data policy nails it -- obviously you need to be able to share a token between your native app and your back-end app and you can do so because the two also share exclusive credentialed access to the FB oauth API.  Of course, the OP wasn't really asking for  this.

Comment: @kingdango, two applications don't need to "share exclusive credentialed access to the FB oauth API". You can retrieve access token from FB "Graph API Explorer" application and use it in your own app.

Answer (score 4):

Each access token is issued only for one app - it cannot be used with different application IDs.